# Copy paste values from one sheet to another via loop

Tags: vba, excel

Maybe somebody can help me with this one very basic problem that I have which is driving me nuts. I just need to copy some data from one sheet to another one depending on its output.

The variables have been defined previously and wMod and wRes stand for worksheets, countP and countC stands for the total amount of cells calculated in another worksheet.

What I need to do is to write a code that would be able to copy data with the value in cell B which has the number 1 in it, paste and paste it in another sheet. When I write the code below though, I only get in column A, sheet wRes the total amount of cells that were stored in variable countP.

You can see what kind of output I get below with the picture I attached.[Data output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQNFR.png) Anybody has any idea why I cannot get the right output? Been stuck with this problem for hours.

```
For i = 3 To countP
        If wMod.Range("B" & i) = 1 Then
            For j = 3 To countC1
                wMod.Range("A" & i).Copy wRes.Range("A" & j)
            Next j
        End If
Next i
```

Comment: Did you already tried to look for an answer in this site? This question looks to be answered several times before.

Comment: I've been looking for an answer for this a lot of times both on this website and on others.  If there are any answers that might be similar, they either only contain the loop without the "if" or it contains only one variable that is changing. If you see anything that is relatively close to an answer mentioned previously, please drop me a link and I'll check it out.

Comment: Is the problem that in your j loop you are copying the same cell each time as i doesn't change? Perhaps you need an Offset.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my problem. But could you maybe clarify how I could use offset in this instance? I am not really experienced with using it yet.

Comment: @BackseatBoss could you maybe show us a sample as to where you would like to copy the cell in column A if the cell in Column B = 1? Where would you like to paste it in wRes? at the moment you are copying the value of cell A as many times as countC1...

Comment: @Xabier that's my problem, but I can't understand why. I can't really upload the entire sheet due to confidential info on there, but basically imagine that there is a separate sheet where there is a column (column A) with IDs (let's say going from 1 to 40).  Each of them have one of the two categories (Column B), either category 1 or 2. What I want to do is copy all the ID numbers in category 1 from column A to a new sheet. But I seemingly cannot do that because there is a problem in the loop. Unless you could suggest something else?

Comment: Think you need to clarify what needs to be copied when a 1 is found in column B.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will check the Last Row with Data on Sheet1 Column A, then it will loop from row 2 to the Last and check if Column B = 1, then it will check the last row with data on Sheet2 Column A, and paste the value in the next row (ie. next empty row).

It goes like so:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'find the last row with data on Column A in Sheet1

For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop from row 2 to last
    If ws.Range("B" & i) = 1 Then 'if column B in Sheet1 = 1 then
    LastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row with data on Sheet2 Column A
    ws2.Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 1) = ws.Range("A" & i)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```